# Pushing a comment to a specific array in Mongoose, Nodejs+Mongodb+AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Ok i have a collection of resources which contains products details. Inside resources collection i have a Log[] array which contains the posts or comments about this resource with a creation date.

These are my collections:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    first: String,
    last: String,
    email: String,
    roles: [String],
    logs: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Log'
    }]
});


var LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    posted_by: { type: String, ref: 'User'},
    content:  String,
    date      : String,
});

var ResourcesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    serialnumber: String,
    modelno: String,
    description: String,
    logs: [LogSchema]
});
```

In AngularJs i have a dropdown which retrieves all the resources from the Database and it displays the names of each resource it retrieves. Also, i have a textarea where the user inputs the comment to the specific resource who selects it from the dropdown above.

The thing i'm trying to do is, when a user selects the specific item from the dropdown above, is to input the text in the textarea below and when the post button is pressed, is to make a push to Logs array to the specific resource.

here is my HTML form

```
                     <select ng-model="selectedResource" ng-options="resource.name for resource in resources" class="form-control" >
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            {{selectedResource.logs}}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>


                    <textarea rows="3" cols="50" placeholder="content" ng-model="log.content">
                    </textarea>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>


                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addLog()">Post</button>
```

My controller

```
app.controller("ActivitylogCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/activitylog')
        .success(function(response) {   
            $scope.resources = response;
    });

    $scope.all = function(){
        $http.get('/activitylog')
        .success(function(response) {
            var log = "";
            $scope.logs = response;
            $scope.log = "";
        });
    };

    $scope.addLog = function() {
        console.log($scope.log);
        $http.post('/activitylog', $scope.log)
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.logs.push(response);
            $scope.all();
        });
    };

    $scope.all();

});
```

And my POST

```
app.post("/activitylog", function(req, res){
    var selectedResource = req.body.selectedResource;
    var content = req.body.content;
    var date = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/,' ').replace(/\..+/,'');
   Resources.findByIdAndUpdate(
    selectedResource, 
        {$push: {"logs": {content: content, date: date}}},
        {safe : true, upsert: true},
        function(err, model) {
            console.log(err);
        }
   );
});
```

I receive the following error if i leave the $push operator as it is. If i delete the "$" i receive NULL in my console log

> { [MongoError: unknown top level operator: $push]   name:
>   'MongoError',   message: 'unknown top level operator: $push',
>   waitedMS: 0,   ok: 0,   errmsg: 'unknown top level operator: $push',
>   code: 2 } { [MongoError: unknown top level operator: $push]   name:
>   'MongoError',   message: 'unknown top level operator: $push',
>   waitedMS: 0,   ok: 0,   errmsg: 'unknown top level operator: $push',
>   code: 2 }

Comment: Angular has nothing to do with mongo/mongoose. When people see a wall of irrelevant code, they are much less likely to help. The only code that has anything to do with your actual question are the first and last code blocks, and the error itself.

Comment: Yeah i know! I put the AngularJs only to show if the Controller take the resource id from the dropdown and pass it correctly to POST method

Comment: And that should have been debugged by you. It's easy enough to `console.log(req.body)`, and have half your question disappear.

Comment: Any idea what version of MongoDB you're using?

Comment: i Use 3.2 version of mongodb